# JAVA How will an IF statement evaluate if || (OR) as well as && (AND) are placed in the same if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators, operator-precedence

Currently I am working on a little personal project to help myself learn about coding.
I'm wondering for future reference if I can combine logical operators of different types in a single if statement.

For example if I had

```
if (n == 0 || n == 1 && m == 0 || m == 1) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Would it check if either parts of the left side are true, then if either parts of the right are true, or would it do something similar to checking if both of the middle ones are true?

Does using parenthesis change anything
For example

```
if ((n == 0 || n == 1) && (m == 0 || m == 1)) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Edit:
From a suggestion I tried it out, but when i put three variables it started acting weird
Here's my test:

```
int n = 1;
int m = 1;
int o = 1;

if (n == 0 || n == 1 && m == 0 || m == 1 && o == 0 || o == 1) {
  System.out.println("True");
}
else {
  System.out.println("False");
}

if ((n == 0 || n == 1) && (m == 0 || m == 1) && (o == 0 || o == 1)) {
  System.out.println("True");
}
else {
  System.out.println("False");
}
```

if all of them are 1 or 0, they both evaluate true, if n or m is not 1 or 0 the top evaluates true but the bottom does not.

However if o is not 0 or 1 both of them are false.
I have found that parenthesis do in fact make a difference, but I can't quite tell why it's acting the way it is.

Comment: Why not simply write a little program to test the results -- create your own "truth table"?

Comment: Next, a useful and practical tool to learn is the Venn diagram, which will also bring you the correct answer to your question

Comment: Use brackets to make your intention clear.  It'll make it easier to understand in 6 months time.

Comment: Why don't you just look up the language specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` has a higher precedence then `||`, so `n == 0 || n == 1 && m == 0 || m == 1` equals `n == 0 || (n == 1 && m == 0) || m == 1`. You may check the precedence table [here](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html).

Comment: I strongly recommend to not rely on it, however. This is not obvious and reduces readability.

Comment: On the contrary, it is the redundant parentheses that reduce readability. It should be obvious to any competent programmer. Operator precedence is first taught in third grade. It's not an esoteric concept.